# On AWS Amplify, what are the best build settings to deploy a custom toolkit Nodejs/Express/Apollo GraphQL API?

Tags: amazon-web-services

After deploying my React UI to AWS Amplify, I am attempting to deploy the API built on Node/Express/Apollo Client/Mongo Atlas. I am using a custom toolkit using Apollo Server, not Amazon's GraphQL service. Sadly the build process fails without explanation. **Am I using the correct build settings, or even the correct AWS instance?**

`package.json`

```
    "main": "server.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.x",
        "npm": "6.x"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon -e js,graphql -w . -w .env server.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "apollo-server-express": "^2.3.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "file-type": "^16.2.0",
        "graphql": "^15.3.0",
        "mongodb": "^3.6.0",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
    }
}
```

AWS build

```
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - ENV_VAR=foo
        - npm start
```

Build response (`Frontend`) (This is the whole thing..)

```
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2021-03-16T04:24:43.688Z [INFO]: > fsevents@1.2.13 install /codebuild/output/src628831181/src/camval-api-aws/node_modules/fsevents
                                 > node install.js
```

Build logs (This is the whole thing..)

```
2021-03-16T04:24:15.787Z [INFO]: # Cloning repository: git@github.com:dr-spaceman/camval-api-aws.git
2021-03-16T04:24:15.796Z [INFO]: Agent pid 131
2021-03-16T04:24:15.846Z [INFO]: Identity added: /root/.ssh/git_rsa (/root/.ssh/git_rsa)
2021-03-16T04:24:16.190Z [INFO]: Cloning into 'camval-api-aws'...
2021-03-16T04:24:16.714Z [INFO]: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.255.112' to the list of known hosts.
2021-03-16T04:24:17.583Z [INFO]: # Switching to commit: e6989a38ca546d397238697f7c7253aaabd2d076
2021-03-16T04:24:17.591Z [INFO]: Agent pid 141
2021-03-16T04:24:17.594Z [INFO]: Identity added: /root/.ssh/git_rsa (/root/.ssh/git_rsa)
2021-03-16T04:24:17.597Z [INFO]: Note: switching to 'e6989a38ca546d397238697f7c7253aaabd2d076'.
                                 You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
                                 changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
                                 state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
                                 If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
                                 do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
                                 git switch -c <new-branch-name>
                                 Or undo this operation with:
                                 git switch -
                                 Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
2021-03-16T04:24:17.597Z [INFO]: HEAD is now at e6989a3 add package-lock.json
2021-03-16T04:24:17.603Z [INFO]: Successfully cleaned up Git credentials
2021-03-16T04:24:17.603Z [INFO]: # Checking for Git submodules at: /codebuild/output/src628831181/src/camval-api-aws/.gitmodules
2021-03-16T04:24:17.626Z [INFO]: # Retrieving cache...
2021-03-16T04:24:17.662Z [INFO]: # Extracting cache...
2021-03-16T04:24:17.669Z [INFO]: # Extraction completed
2021-03-16T04:24:17.669Z [INFO]: # Retrieving environment cache...
2021-03-16T04:24:17.703Z [INFO]: # Retrieved environment cache
2021-03-16T04:24:36.170Z [INFO]: ## Starting Frontend Build
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2021-03-16T04:24:43.688Z [INFO]: > fsevents@1.2.13 install /codebuild/output/src628831181/src/camval-api-aws/node_modules/fsevents
                                 > node install.js
```

Comment: I think having `npm start` in Build Settings is wrong since it will not run NodeJS since Amplify will serve Static Files only on S3/CloudFront. If you need NodeJS runtime so you need to add api with REST endpoint and have Lambda code which will be run on NodeJS (processing what you wanted with `npm start`)